# convergence in distribution when parameters converges almost surely

Tags: convergence, slutsky-theorem

let $X_n$ be sequence of random variables with the associated distribution $N(\mu_n,\beta_n+E)$. That is a sequence of normally distributed random variables with changing mean and variance.  $\beta_n$  is scalar sequence. $\mu_n$ is a sequence of random variables. 
It is given that $$\mu_n \xrightarrow{as}M$$ where M is scalar and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \beta_n=0$. Can i say that $X_n \xrightarrow{d}N(M,E)$

My approach : $X_n=Y_n+\mu_n$ where $Y_n \sim N(0,\beta_n+E)$. By slutsky's theorem, $Y_n+\mu_n \xrightarrow{d}Y+M$ where $Y\sim N(0,E)$. Thus the claim.

Another approach is that is found somewhere is the characteristic function associated with $$N(\mu_n,\beta_n+E)$$ will converge to the characteristic function of  $N(M,E)$ and that convergence in characteristic functions imply convergence in distribution,

Comment: is $\mu(n)$ supposed to be a random variable?

Comment: Yes. One of the parameter of the distribution is converging almost surely. Does that imply the the resulting distributions will also converge??